# In ffmpeg, how do I process subtitle streams when using filter_complex with trim and atrim?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg filtergraphs to extract and concatenate chunks of videos. As a simple example, consider this, which takes an input file with a video stream and an audio stream and produces a 20-second output that includes timestamps 00:10-00:20 and 00:30-00:40 of the input:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv \
    -filter_complex "\
        [0:0]trim=start=10:end=20,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
        [0:1]atrim=start=10:end=20,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; \
        [0:0]trim=start=30:end=40,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; \
        [0:1]atrim=start=30:end=40,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2]; \
        [v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]\
    " -map [v] -map [a] \
    -c:0 libx264 -preset:0 ultrafast \
    -c:1 ac3 -b:1 128k -ac:1 2 out.mkv
```

Is there a way to process subtitle streams in a similar way so that the subtitles will match the other, trimmed streams? I'm looking for something that'll work from the command line to be part of a non-interactive batch process.

### Update - solution

With feedback from @kesh, we arrived at using the `concat` demuxer to process the subtitles and combine that with reading the audio and video streams into a complex filtergraph. First, you need a concat input file like:

```
file 'in.mkv'
inpoint 10
outpoint 20

file 'in.mkv'
inpoint 30
outpoint 40
```

Then, if subtitles are stream 5, for example, just:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv \
    -f concat -i concat-file \
    -filter_complex "\
        [0:0]trim=start=10:end=20,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
        [0:1]atrim=start=10:end=20,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; \
        [0:0]trim=start=30:end=40,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; \
        [0:1]atrim=start=30:end=40,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2]; \
        [v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]\
    " -map [v] -map [a] -map 1:5 \
    -c:0 libx264 -preset:0 ultrafast \
    -c:1 ac3 -b:1 128k -ac:1 2 \
    -c:2 copy out.mkv
```

Comment: In my experience, a concat file like this appears to seek backwards from the `inpoint` to the nearest keyframe much like `-ss` does (and regardless of `-accurate_seek`).  Thus, using it introduces sync drift on the subs when mixed with trimming that doesn't seek.  Trimming to individual mkv files instead appears to work okay (ts files do not support subs, it seems) but I sometimes have trouble with concatenating short clips in certain codecs afterwards.  (I should probably trim to a lossless format and then re-encode to lossy only after the final concat... but I have yet to try that.)

Comment: @juanitogan Any update on your experience? I have yet to actually implement this, but I'm worried about the same syncing issues, which I've experienced before when trying to play with subs.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done any cutting since then. What I mostly do is use `trim` to modify sections of video various ways so as to not mess with audio or sub length. But I'm pretty confident my last statement earlier is the way to go. Thus, you have two options: 1) always cut to keyframes (like lossless-cut does); or 2) cut in two steps (lossless and/or uncompressed being the first step). Because there is no `strim` (yet?) I'm guessing you need to use `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -ss 10 -to 20 ... part1.mkv` to trim accurately to multiple files. Then `ffmpeg -i "concat:part1.mkv|part2.mkv" ... out.mkv`.

Comment: Other things that may help: lossless-cut's smart cut feature: https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut/issues/126. avcut (for h264): https://github.com/anyc/avcut. I use VirtualDub2 as a fast way to find frame numbers and exact time (much better than VLC for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. FFmpeg filtergraph can only add subtitle text to video (e.g., `subtitle` and `ass` filters). It has no way of manipulating subtitle streams.

Your best bet is the [`concat` demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate). You can list the same file multiple times with different start and end times. In your batch file, you can create the concat list in memory and pipe it into FFMpeg.

[edit]

Assuming that `in.mkv` has it all: video, audio, and subtitle streams. Then you can prepare a concat demuxer file like:

`listing.txt`

```
ffconcat version 1.0

file in.mkv
inpoint 10
outpoint 20

file in.mkv
inpoint 30
outpoint 40
```

Basically, list the input file multiple times with different start and end timestamps.

Then,

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i listing.txt -map [v] -map [a] -map [s] -c copy out.mkv
```

would copy all 3 streams to `out.mkv`.

Disclaimer: I have not verified it myself, but it should work on paper.

Comment: So... I can use filter_complex for a/v streams, then use concat to build a separate file with subs and then one final pass to copy streams into a final output file. Not sure that's exactly what you were suggesting, but I think that works!

Comment: Not quite. It's a lot simpler than that if I understand what you want to do. See the edit in my post.

Comment: Oh right, I get that I could just use concat on all the streams, but in my experience, it doesn't do nearly as well at handling the a/v streams as a filtergraph does. I haven't tried to understand all the details, but it seems that the stream timestamps get thrown off, which can distort audio and cause the cut locations to be off from where I want them. With a filtergraph, I can calculate timestamps down to the frame and extract exactly what I want. It works every time.

Comment: ...and also, the filtergraph often gets additional things in it, like cropping or deinterlacing filters. If I just used concat, I'd probably have to make multiple, lossy encoding passes.

Comment: I see. Just speculating, but I wonder if the problem goes away if you cut on the keyframes.

Comment: As for subtitle stream splicing with your workflow, you can perhaps use the `concat` demuxer as the second input (use stream directive to only use subtitle stream) and map it along with filtered a/v streams. If this works, only 1 ffmpeg run for the job.

Comment: Bingo. I wasn't seeing it, but the concat file is just another input. It works all in one command. Now I just have to work up something to build the concat file. Thanks! I couldn't say about the keyframes, but it sounds reasonable guess.